# Bridged Network not working on Ubuntu Guest, Windows 8 Host using VMWare

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 11 (Ubuntu 15.04 Guest, Windows 8.1 Host) and bridged networking is operating fine on my home network; however, when I try using the same configuration on my work network the connection inside Ubuntu constantly tries to establish a connection -- yet never does.  Does anyone know what is likely the problem or how I might go about troubleshooting this issue?

**EDIT**

I ran the following command but only continually get requests being sent. I never receive a response.

```
:~$ sudo dhcpdump -i eth0
  TIME: 2015-07-31 07:18:07.568
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (0:c:29:d5:6a:db) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: b45ef25d
  SECS: 6
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:0c:29:d5:6a:db:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        192.168.221.128
OPTION:  12 (  6) Host name                 ubuntu
OPTION:  55 ( 18) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
    28 (Broadcast address)
     2 (Time offset)
     3 (Routers)
    15 (Domainname)
     6 (DNS server)
   119 (Domain Search)
    12 (Host name)
    44 (NetBIOS name server)
    47 (NetBIOS scope)
    26 (Interface MTU)
   121 (Classless Static Route)
    42 (NTP servers)
   121 (Classless Static Route)
   249 (MSFT - Classless route)
    33 (Static route)
   252 (MSFT - WinSock Proxy Auto Detect)
    42 (NTP servers)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2015-07-31 07:18:11.069
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (0:c:29:d5:6a:db) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: b45ef25d
  SECS: 10
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:0c:29:d5:6a:db:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        192.168.221.128
OPTION:  12 (  6) Host name                 ubuntu
OPTION:  55 ( 18) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
    28 (Broadcast address)
     2 (Time offset)
     3 (Routers)
    15 (Domainname)
     6 (DNS server)
   119 (Domain Search)
    12 (Host name)
    44 (NetBIOS name server)
    47 (NetBIOS scope)
    26 (Interface MTU)
   121 (Classless Static Route)
    42 (NTP servers)
   121 (Classless Static Route)
   249 (MSFT - Classless route)
    33 (Static route)
   252 (MSFT - WinSock Proxy Auto Detect)
    42 (NTP servers)
```

Comment: Have you obtained authorisation from the administrator of your work network and registered the VM with them?

Comment: Yes, I did but yes that would have been definitely something I would have needed to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem by changing the VM Settings->Network Adapter from Virtual Adapter "VMNet0 (auto-Bridged)" or whatever its called, to "Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network" with "Replicate physical network connection state" checked. I'm starting VMWare Workstation as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me:

1. In the VMWare open: **Edit > Virtual Network Editor...**
2. On the bottom: **Change Settings** (Allow root privileges)
3. In the top list select VMNet0. *It's type should be "Briged"*
4. In the VMnet Information section change the **"Bridged to"** to the adapter in which your host has connection.
5. Apply, **OK**

I applied these changes while the VM was running, and it worked for me. But you can also do it while the VM is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the MAC Address that I saw for the VMWare adapters through windows `ipconfig /all` was different than the MAC address I saw in Ubuntu's `ifconfig` so I added that one too.  After that I would eventually get a response from the DHCP server with some valid information; however, I still wouldn't get a connection.  It wasn't until I added a static ip address before I was able to get it to connect.

Comment: I'd hate to say "well duh" but of course it will be. The IP address you see in Windows `ipconfig /all` will be the MAC address of the adapter Windows uses to connect to the VM. It's no different to a network card in your Windows machine, a cable, and a second network card in another machine (the VM). Of course you have to look at the VM's `ifconfig` to see the VM's MAC address, you're not going to get another computer's MAC by looking at your own `ipconfig` in Windows!

Comment: Well it appeared to have my connection fixed but I only checked the connection to my host computer's database... I can access the host computer via ping -- but not the internet (ex: www.google.com). I've tried disabling the windows firewall but that didn't seem to help either